# Python - get list of keys in nested dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"meta": {
    "limit": 25,
    "cache-expiry": 3600
},
"objects": [
    {
        "name": "Elements Automotive",
        "locality": "Dallas",
        "street_address": "8700 Sovereign Row",
        "cuisines": [],
        "postal_code": "75247",
        "categories": [
            "other"
        ],
        "has_menu": false,
        "country": "United States",
        "lat": 32.8191949123164,
        "id": "000e090545789efeca0c",
        "website_url": "http://elementsautomotive.com/",
        "resource_uri": "/v1_0/venue/000e090545789efeca0c/"
    }
]
}
```

How can I get the list of keys ("name","locality", etc.) from Objects?

EDIT: Sorry, the keys are all uniform - I just cut some of them out to keep the code/post short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 data["objects"][0].keys()
 ['cuisines', 'postal_code', 'lat', 'id', 'categories', 'name', 'locality', 'country', 'street_address', 'has_menu', 'website_url', 'resource_uri']
```

Comment: Of course this will only get the keys of the first item in ``objects``.

Comment: @JamesMills, it gets every key as posted

Comment: Yay! I got all of the keys.  Only, I have " u' " in front of each one.  I am not really sure why...(so I am seeing u'name' , u'locality', u'street_address', etc.).

Comment: Ah okay - I assume it's best to leave the 'u' there? I was going to try and list the keys for the user to then choose one, and then return the values for that key and was hoping to just get the bare list.

Comment: if you `print data["objects"][0].keys()[0]` you will see the u is not there, if you really want to remove the u's in your list  `map(str,data["objects"][0].keys())`

Comment: @user3718365 the `u` means that the objects are `unicode` instances instead of instances of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('jsondatafile') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
    print list(data['objects'][0])
```

should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks! I am assuming I need the [0] to tell Python where to start? Also, the results have `'u` before each key.  Is there a way to list the keys without that, or is that just part of calling an API's keys?

Comment: @user3718365 I suspect your question was not very clear as this answer doesn't really answer your question per se :) This will get you the first object in ``objects`` not the list of "keys".

Comment: @mgilson, what's the technical difference in using `list(data['objects'][0]` and `data['objects'][0].keys()` ...if there is one?

Comment: @user3718365 the former returns the dict, the later returns a list of keys. This answer is not the correct one. Please mark Padraic Cunningham's as being correct.

Comment: @user3718365 -- The difference is that `list(dct)` will give you a list even on python3.x.  In python3.x `dct.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object which behaves more like a `set` than a `list`.  For many practical day-to-day things, it doesn't really make any difference.

Comment: @JamesMills -- The former doesn't return a dict -- it returns a list as OP asked.  There is no difference on python2.x, but on python3.x my answer will continue to return a `list` whereas the version using `.keys` will return a `kcit_keys` object...

Comment: @mgilson The OP wanted the keys.

Comment: @JamesMills -- `list(dct)` gives you the keys... since `iter(dct)` gives you an iterator over the dict's keys.

Comment: Oh! :) Haha you are quite right. You do have to admit though ``d.keys()`` is more readable than ``list(d)`` ;)

Comment: @JamesMills -- It makes it more clear that you're just getting (just) the keys, but less clear that you're getting a list -- In fact, in python3.x, You're *not* getting a list :-).  I would argue that they definitely did the right thing in python3.x having `.keys` not return a list, but that's an aside.  If all you want is an iterable object so that you can walk over the dictionary's keys, then `d.keys()` is great -- However, there are definitely (subtle) differences to be aware of.  e.g. in python3.x, if you add a key after calling `d.keys()`, you'll still see the added key.

Comment: I agree -- but as I don't use Python 3.xregularly (*yet?*) I missed that in your answer! Sorry!